# Change file name with regular expression

Tags: regex, gruntjs

I don't know anything about regular expressions.

How can I use a regular expressions to change a file name

I want to change a file name from 'style-dist.css' to style.css

Comment: why do you want to use regular expression ? instead it can be directly replaced by string.Replace method.

Comment: It's part of a gruntfile.js copy - I want to copy a file but change the file name

Answer (score 1):

Regex works if you can find a pattern in the strings you are trying to match/change. For example, here you have given just a single string. I am assuming you are trying to remove the '-dist' part from it? If there is some other pattern, let it be known in your question.

It can be done by

```
new_name = old_name.replace(/-dist/, '');
```

However, if you don't know regex, and have some time, I recommend getting your feet wet in it. As much as you can. Here are some introductory articles:

http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/regular_expressions.html

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml

And here is a more full fledged book(online):
http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/

Answer (score 0):

If using grunt, you'll need to use the `rename` property in the gruntfile.

You can find more information in the grunt docs on [building file objects dynamically](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically).

You could set up your gruntfile to look something like this.

- Note that you'll have to work this into your settings so that everything lines up/etc.
- Note that there are no other guardrails in place here...no error checking, etc.
- Note that you'll need to work out the globs for src and dest locations
- Note that if you are doing this with multiple regex patterns, or your globbing patterns get really complicated, this quickly becomes a nightmare and maybe find a different way to do this.

Code:

```
copy: {
    main: {
      files: [
        {
          expand: true, 
          cwd: '<whatever your cwd is>', 
          src: ['<glob for your -dist.js file location>'], 
          dest: '<glob for a PATH..a PATH>', 
          rename: function(dest, src) {    
            // receives the dest PATH and src and then
            // takes the dest path, appends the modified src using the regex
            return dest + src.replace(/-dist/, '');
         }
       }
```